# How can the current file be overwritten?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

For the following code:

```
fstream file("file.txt", ios::in):

//some code
//"file" changes here

file.close();
file.clear();
file.open("file.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
```

how can the last three lines be changed so that the current file is not closed, but "re-opened" with everything blanked out?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, i.e. what do you mean by 'everything blanked out'? Your question sounds like simply deleting and recreating it would do what you want.

Comment: @us2012 Yes, it's like i want to recreate the file entirely, but it would be good if I don't need to explicitly delete and remake the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you'd like to clear all contents of the file without closing it (i.e. set the file size to 0 by setting EOF position). From what I can find the solution you have presented is the most appealing.

Your other option would be to use an OS-specific function to set the end of file, for example SetEndOfFile() on Windows or truncate() on POSIX.

If you're only looking to begin writing at the beginning of the file, Simon's solution works. Using this without setting end of file may leave you in a situation where you have garbage data past the last position you wrote though.

Answer (score 1):

You can *rewind* the file: put back the *put pointer* to the beginning of the file, so next time you write something, it will overwrite the content of the file.
For this you can use [`seekp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/) like this:

```
fstream file("file.txt", ios::in | ios::out); // Note that you now need
                                              // to open the file for writing
//some code
//"something" changes here

file.seekp(0); // file is now rewinded
```

Note that it doesn't erase any content. Only if you overwrite it so be careful.

Comment: Wouldn't `(ios::in | ios::out) & ~ios::ate` do this as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to avoid passing around the "file.txt" parameter and are trying to implement something like

```
void rewrite( std::ofstream & f )
{
   f.close();
   f.clear();
   f.open(...); // Reopen the file, but we dont know its filename!
}
```

However `ofstream` doesn't provide the filename for the underlying stream, and doesn't provide a way to clear the existing data, so you're kind of out of luck. (It does provide `seekp`, which will let you position the write cursor back to the beginning of the file, but that wont truncate existing content...)

I'd either just pass the filename to the functions that need it

```
void rewrite( std::ostream & f, const std::string & filename )
{
   f.close();
   f.clear();
   f.open( filename.c_str(), ios::out );
}
```

Or package the filestream and filename into a class.

```
class ReopenableStream
{
   public:
     std::string filename;
     std::ofstream f;

     void reopen()
     {
       f.close();
       f.clear();
       f.open( filename.c_str(), ios::out );
     }

     ...
};
```

If you're feeling over zealous you could make `ReopenableStream` actually behave like a stream, so that  you could write `reopenable_stream<<foo;` rather than `reopenable_stream.f<<foo` but IMO that seems like overkill.